# Kendo NumericTextbox not showing digits after decimal point

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have a Kendo NumericTextbox

```
 @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.CalculationValue)
                             .Name("CalculationValue")
                             .Min(0)
                             .Max(99999999)
                             .Format("n")
                             .Decimals(2)
                          )
```

I'm reading a value from the database that is equal to `123.99` but the Kendo NumericTextbox is displaying the value as `123.00.`

I included the relevant culture java script file for `kendo.culture.en-ZA.min.js` and initialized the culture

```
$(function () {
    kendo.culture("en-ZA");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, hopefully this would help someone in future. The culture was forced in the web.config by the following line

```
<globalization culture="en-za" uiCulture="en-za" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

I removed this line and the problem was resolved.